Issue uploading image in File manager after upgrading to 7.4.11
We are currently upgrading our site (https://intranet.qatar.vcu.edu) from EE6.1.6 and PHP Version 7.4.13 to a new environment using EE7.4.11 on a separate Windows Server 2022 with IIS10 and PHP 8.2.12. However, when attempting to upload images via the File Manager, we encounter the following error:
Unexpected error. Check your post_max_size setting in your PHP configuration.
Interestingly, this issue only occurs with image uploads (jpg/png/gif). Other file types, such as PDFs and .mp4 videos, are uploaded without any issues.It happens when we upload the file in the file manager and/or without using drag and drop
To troubleshoot, I modified the PHP.ini settings as follows, but the error persists:
post_max_size: Changed from 8M to 132M
upload_max_filesize: Changed from 40M to 128M
memory_limit: Changed from 128M to 256M
max_execution_time: Set to 600
Please assist in resolving this issue as soon as possible.

I'm not sure why the changes you have made are not working for jpg/png/gif images - that sounds like a bug of some sort and perhaps it would be worth posting a report on the EE Github issues area.
However until you get it resolved, a work-around would be to copy the images you want to add to the site to the appropriate directory on the Windows server (by FTP or similar) and once the images have been copied over, then synchronise the image folder concerned within EE. This will have the same effect as uploading images to the server - in that the images uploaded will appear in the Files manager interface, be available for adding to entries on the site, and if appropriate will have any "image transformations" specified for the folder applied.
Separately, I am aware from other reports that hosting EE on IIS can be problematic. There is a server compatibility wizard you can run that maybe worth doing to check that your IIS installation meets EE's requirements.
HTH

